# Finding multiple streaks in data and listing results with a limit

Tags: php, mysql

I've been struggling with this for some time now.  I've tried using multiple tutorials on the subject to no avail, so here I am hoping someone can solve this for me.

Use this table as a example:

```
id || tourneyid  || playerid || standing
1  || 1          || 1        || 1      
2  || 1          || 2        || 2      
3  || 1          || 3        || 3      
4  || 2          || 1        || 1     
5  || 2          || 2        || 3      
6  || 2          || 3        || 2      
7  || 3          || 1        || 2      
8  || 3          || 2        || 1      
9  || 3          || 3        || 3      
10 || 4          || 1        || 2     
11 || 4          || 2        || 1
12 || 4          || 3        || 3
13 || 5          || 1        || 3
14 || 5          || 2        || 2
15 || 5          || 3        || 1
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is finding the best streak for each playerid where their standing = 1, and then listing the results in php form with a limit of the top 5 (actual table much larger) streaks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This one has been bothering me for quite some time with no success.

Comment: So just to clarify the question, you are looking for the most 'consecutive' (by id) tournaments where someone has finished in first place?

Comment: That is correct Avatar, and then list the top 5 results.